# Fixing the value of a variable that changes in terms of another

Tags: python

Suppose I have a global variable `time` that is incremented by 1 unit with every update of the window according to some FPS (for example in Pygame). Then suppose I have another variable defined in terms of `time`, like this:

```
def function():
    global time

    t = time // 3
    final = t + 100
    
    if t < final:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

The behavior I want is that the variable `final` stores the value of `t` just when the function is first called and then `final` becomes a constant, while `t` keeps running together with `time`. So, `final` would not always be 100 ahead of `t`, which is what happens, but would be 100 ahead of `t` just when the function first captures `t` and then would keep that number unchanged. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `final` global and check if it has been set.

```
final = None
def function():
    global time, final

    t = time // 3
    if not final: final = t + 100  # update once
    
    if t < final:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

You can also create an attribute on the function itself.

```
def func():
    global time

    t = time // 3
    if not 'final' in dir(func): func.final = t + 100  # update once
    
    print(func.final)
    
    if t < func.final:
        pass
    else:
        pass

time=10
func()
time=20
func()
time=30
func()
```

Output

```
103
103
103
```

Comment: Nice, that works, but I think this new global variable will restrict me when I generalize some things.

Comment: Without a global variable, you will need to pass `final` into the function and return the updated value

Comment: You can also attach an attribute to the function. Answer updated.